# German equivalent of “true of something”

Tags: english-to-german, phrase

I translate *true* as *wahr*, but I couldn’t establish a sentence like its English original. Could you please elaborate on my attempt.

> That is not true of motivation in the classroom setting.
>
> Das ist über die Motivation im Klassenzimmer Einstellung nicht wahr.

I perceive *true of motivation*  as a noun here. Am I wrong?

Comment: You should remember to capitalise *I* (the pronoun) in English.

Comment: Could you please explain what the sentence in English mean? Normally, I would translate "true of" as "das gilt für .." or "das betrifft ... "

Comment: Are you sure that the english sentence is correct? To me it seems like it should be `That is not true about the motivation in the classroom setting.` Could you explain in different words what it is supposed to mean?

Comment: @Iris the whole phrase was: "Which of the following is not true of motivation in the classroom setting?"

Comment: @Bergmann, I still don't understand it.

Comment: The English sentence is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Yes (*true of motivation* is not a noun).

About your translation: the German word "Einstellung" refers to a setting as in "browser settings", not a situation or scenario as in the original sentence. If you just leave it out and change "über" to "für", you have a grammatically correct German sentence.

Depending on the context, better translations might be:

- Das ist bei der Motivation im Klassenzimmer nicht der Fall.
- Das trifft auf die Motivation in der Klassenzimmersituation nicht zu.

Comment: Instead of _Klassenzimmersituation_ you could say _im schulischen Rahmen_ or _Unterricht_ [cf. Linguee](http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/classroom+setting.html)

Answer (score 3):

I have problems with your example, so I chose a different one to explain “to be true of something”. The translation is [“zutreffend sein für”](http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/to+be+true+of.html), [“auf etwas zutreffen”](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=to%20be%20true%20of&l=deen&in=&lf=de) or [“für jmdn./etw. gelten”](http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/be%20true%20of.html).

An [example](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=236218&idForum=2&lang=de&lp=ende) is:

> Yet it is certainly true that we have to be careful with complex technology, but this **is not only true of** AI, it **is also true of** nuclear power.

which can be translated to:

> [...] das **trifft nicht nur auf** KI **zu**, sondern **gilt auch für** Kernkraft.